# Why is no non empty open suset of $\mathbb{R}$ open in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was studying about topologies of metric subspaces and superspaces. I came across this example:

Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the intersection of $\mathbb{R}$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

But no non empty open suset of $\mathbb{R}$ open in $\mathbb{C}$.

I understand the first one, it simply follows from the definition of topology of a metric subspace, but i don't think that i follow the second one.

It would be nice if someone could explain the second part to me .

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is open in $\mathbb{C}$. Given $x \in O$, then by definition, there must exist some $\epsilon > 0$ with

$$|y - x| < \epsilon \implies y \in O$$

But $x + \frac{\epsilon}{2} i$ satisfies this, and is not in $\mathbb{R}$.